# DataSource is null but has been filled previously

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataview

I have one function filling 5 DataGridView's the same way, and another function called when I change the value of a textbox to order the dgv's according to the textbox's text

Every dgv has its own text box so there are separate "tbx.text_changed" events, all calling to my function.

I also have a function sorting the dgv's by a certain column, which is called after I filled the dgv's.
So in order, I fill the dgv's, then order them by the 3rd column called Commentaires, then enter some text to order them from the 1st column called Champ

Yesterday I could search for text in every dgv but one.
I tried to fix the problem, but today I can search in only the one which was previously bugged.

Every other dgv throws a "null reference"error when I enter a letter in their textbox. the NullReference points out that the DataSources are empty, however they shouldn't be.

It was the same error for the lonely dgv yesterday.

Here's my function to look for text:

```
       if (text == "")
            {
                lblTexte.Text = "";
                lblCompteur.Text = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                dgv.Rows[i].Selected = false;
            }
            return;
        }
        if (dgv.RowCount < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable d = new DataTable();
            lblTexte.Text = "Champ répondant au critère: ";
            tbx.SelectionStart = text.Length;
            tbx.Text = text.ToUpper();
            if ((dgv.DataSource.GetType()).Equals(typeof(DataView)))
            {
                d = ((DataView)dgv.DataSource).Table;
            }
            else
            {
                d = dgv.DataSource as DataTable;
            }
            DataRow[] row = d.Select("Champ like '%" + text + "%'");
            List<int> listeIndex = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataRow r in row)
                {
                    if (((DataRowView)dgv.Rows[i].DataBoundItem).Row == r)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                        listeIndex.Add(i);
                    }
                    else if (!listeIndex.Contains(i))
                    {
                        dgv.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
        {
            dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        }
        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count == 0 && text == "")
        {
            lblCompteur.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lblCompteur.Text = dgv.SelectedRows.Count.ToString();
        }
```

Here is my function to fill the datagridviews:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("source");
        if (source.Any())
        {
            //Creation datatable
            dt.Columns.Add("Champ", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Valeur", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Commentaires", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            foreach (Enregistrement enr in source)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { enr.cle, enr.valeur, ControleurTypes.verificationEnregistrement(enr) });
            }
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            grille.DataSource = bs;
            return dt;
        }
        return dt;
```

And here's my function to sort them:

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dgv.DataSource;
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;
        DataView view = dt.DefaultView;
        view.Sort = "Commentaires DESC";
        dgv.DataSource = view;
```

In the end, I can't manage to sort my Datatables,
I believe it is due to some conversion problem.
The error occurs in the function I use to order the datatables using the textbox's text.

```
DataRow[] row = d.Select("Champ like '%" + text + "%'");
```

This line throws the error "System.NullReferenceException"
the debugger says that d is null.

I'm not quite experienced in Dgv's / DataViews / DataTables, so I'd appreciate if you took the time to help me find out what is the problem here.

Comment: I think source may be empty : if (source.Any())

Comment: I did some tests and there's always something in Source

Comment: Okay so I got some feedback saying that i shouldn't use BindingSource / dataTable to interact with Data. I'm trying something with BindingLists and i'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer.
I switched to BindingLists and it was way Easier.

Function to search for the text:

```
    List<int> tableauIndex = new List<int>();
        if (text == "")
        {
            lblTexte.Text = "";
            lblCompteur.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dgv.Rows[i].Selected = false;
            }
            return;
        }
        if (dgv.RowCount < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            text = text.ToUpper();
            lblTexte.Text = "Champ répondant au critère: ";
            tbx.SelectionStart = text.Length;
            tbx.Text = text;
            BindingList<EnregCommente> bl = (BindingList<EnregCommente>)dgv.DataSource;
            var sortedListInstance = from EnregCommente enr in bl
                                     where(enr.cle.Contains(text))
                                     select enr;
            foreach (EnregCommente enr in sortedListInstance)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(enr.cle);
            }
            foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dgv.Rows)
            {
                foreach(EnregCommente enr in sortedListInstance)
                {
                    if (r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == enr.cle)
                    {
                        tableauIndex.Add(r.Index);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
            {
                if (tableauIndex.Contains(row.Index))
                {
                    dgv.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    dgv.Rows[row.Index].Selected = false;
                }
            }
            foreach (int i in tableauIndex)
            {
                dgv.Rows[i].Selected = true;
            }
        }
        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
        {
            dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        }
        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count == 0 && text == "")
        {
            lblCompteur.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lblCompteur.Text = dgv.SelectedRows.Count.ToString();
        }
```

Function to sort by a column :

```
BindingList<EnregCommente> bl = (BindingList<EnregCommente>)dgv.DataSource;
        var sortedListInstance = new BindingList<EnregCommente>(bl.OrderByDescending(x => x.commentaire).ToList());
        dgv.DataSource = sortedListInstance;
```

Function to fill the grids:

```
            BindingList<EnregCommente> bl = new BindingList<EnregCommente>();
        foreach (Enregistrement e in source)
        {
            EnregCommente enr = new EnregCommente(e);
            bl.Add(enr);
        }
        grille.DataSource = bl;
        return bl;
```

I had to create a new class to fill the grids, it's just taking the values of Enregistrement to put them in a cleaner way into my binding list.